# How to prevent npm install removes local added packages

Tags: npm, npm-install

Looked to numerous SO questions and answers, however have not found the answer to fix the following issue.

On my local machine I run *npm* from the folder *node_modules*. This folder contains several packages from GIT-sources, however there are two folders containing custom made scripts. Each time I update package with *npm install*  my two custom folders are gone. Luckily I made a backup and was able to restore these two. But it's also annoying, because what else is removed that I don't see??

I'm on npm version 6.13.2

Any help is of course highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can prevent npm from removing those folders because they are not in your `package.json`.

Although there are two things that you can do which are as follows,

1. Create npm modules for those 2 scripts and update their entries in your `package.json`. Here is a link for 'how to create and publish node module'.

```
https://www.guru99.com/node-js-modules-create-publish.html
```

2. Create a repo for those 2 scripts and update their git paths in your package.json.

Comment: I'll have a look into the post. At first glance it seems quit a hassle to prevent npm from removing folders.